# Text View overshooting in Table View.

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

In the Storyboard, the Text View is fine. I drag it into a tabel view cell in sotryboard like this.
[image]

However, in the runtime, I got this:
[image]

and this:
[image]

My configuration is:
[image]
[image]

### Any idea?

Comment: Do you ever change the frame of the TextView in your code?

Comment: @Nerrolken No. I just drag the object into the table view cell's content cell..... Let me double check my code.